# IcCube - excluding members on schema level

Tags: iccube

EDIT (copy&paste errors):

I would like to use the time wizard dimension and having only dates being not in the future. But since I have to set an end date, which I obviusly would not like to change every day by hand, I would like to set this very high and remove afterwards all the members lying in the future. 
For this I tried to use the "Advanced" methods "Scripts" and "Perspectives". I would prefer the first, since it would make those members vanish and not only being invisible, but if there is no way of doing so, the second would be ok as well.

If I filter those dates in an MDX statement, everything works fine:

```
filter([date].[date].[day].members, [date].CurrentMember.KEY < now())
```

Using a Script I tried to Drop the members:

```
DROP member filter([date].[date].[date].members, [date].[date].CurrentMember.KEY > now())
```

and it gave me a syntax error: syntax error: unexpected statement '(' (OPEN_PAREN)

Trying to use a perspective

```
-filter([date].[date].[day].members, [date].CurrentMember.KEY > now())
```

told me: syntax error: unknown function/property 'KEY'

What do I have to do, to get rid of those dates? I would like to do this while loading the schema at the latest.

Comment: any reason for mixing [import_dates] and [dates] hierarchies ?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up with copy&paste... I fixed it. There is only one dimension. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you try with: -filter([date].[date].[day].members, [date].CurrentMember.properties('KEY',TYPED) > now())

Comment: That works. Is there a method, to drop those members, instead of hiding them via Perspective? I would like to upvote you, but I can't upvote a comment...

Comment: no, I don't think there is unless you go for security. But we've to change the wizard so it can grow. It's the easiest solution.

Comment: You can create a set in the script with the filtered dates and use it for your reports too